# Question about the definition of the resolvent set

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

In Evans' PDE book (p. 437) he defines the resolvent set of a closed linear operator, $A:D(A)\to A(D(A))$, on a Banach space, $X$, as follows:

i) We say a real number $\lambda$ belongs to $\rho(A)$, the $resolvent\text{ }set$ of $A$, provided the operator $\lambda I-A:D(A) \to X$ is one-to-one and onto.

My question is the following:

How do we know that the range of $\lambda I -A$ is $X$? My thought is that it has to do with the fact that $A$ is closed, but I am not sure how (we are not explicitly given that $D(A)$ is dense in $X$ either).

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand you correctly; we do not KNOW that $\text{ran}\,\lambda I-A=X$, the resolvent set CONTAINS those $\lambda$ with this (and another) property. But there is no way to write down the set explicitly without knowing what $A$ looks like - and even then it is most often very difficult if possible at all.

Comment: Right, my question is that it seems like the operator for which Evans defines the resolvent set is rather arbitrary, but he seems to state that the range of $\lambda I - A$ is $X$ for $\lambda\in\rho(A)$, and I am wondering if this is in fact what he means, and if so, how do we know that.

Comment: Perhaps some motivation for my question would help also: I am going through the proof in Pazy's book of the Hille-Yosida theorem for contraction semigroups, and in the backwards direction, we have that $1\in\rho(A)$ and we need $(I-A)D(A)=X$ in the last step to show that $A$ is the generator of a $C_{0}$-semigroup. However, I am not sure why this equality should hold in this situation.

Comment: Isn't $\text{ran}\,\lambda I-A=X$ true **by definition** for each $\lambda\in\rho(A)$? That's exactly the "onto" part of the definition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merely a definition, not a statement to be proved. The requirement for $\lambda$ to be in the resolvent set is that the operator $\lambda I-A$ maps $D(A)$ bijectively onto $X$. This is further emphasized by next item of the definition, where the resolvent operator $R_\lambda$ defined on all of $X$.

In infinite dimensions, it is quite possible for a linear operator to map a proper subspace onto the entire space. For example, the backward shift in $\ell^2$, 
$$
Sx = (x_2, x_3, x_4, \dots) 
$$
maps the proper subspace $\{x\in \ell^2 : x_1=0\}$ (which is not even dense) onto $\ell^2$.

Comment: Thanks! And another reference I've found for this same definition of the resolvent set of a closed operator is p. 419 of Lax's "Functional Analysis" (it exactly agrees with what you've written here).